# Issue in ASP .NET C# Code upgrade from VS2012 to VS2015

Tags: c#

I am trying to Upgrade C# code from VS2012 to VS2015.When I open my project in VS2015 , it showing error "NUGET Package restore fail for Project XXX. Unable to Find versio 1.7.1 of package jQuery.vsdoc".
I tried to install jQuery.vsdoc 1.7.1 through Package Manager Console, but getting error "Some NuGet Packages are missing from the solution . Click to retore from online package sources." Also, jQuery.vsdoc 1.7.1 is not available online .

Comment: try this on vs2015 `Install-Package jQuery-vsdoc` and let us now the results

Comment: 1.7.1 has been deprecated from that package. I'd suggest upgrade your jQuery library and utilize a more recent vsdoc package. Alternatively just do a minor upgrade to 1.7.2, or manually add the file to the solution until you upgrade jQuery

Comment: `Install-Package jQuery-vsdoc -Version 1.7.2`

Comment: I tried both :Install-Package jQuery-vsdoc -Version 1.7.2 and Install-Package jQuery-vsdoc. But getting error " Install-Package : Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph. Restore the packages 
before performing any operations.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package jQuery-vsdoc
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo    : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    +FullyQualifiedErrorId :NuGetMissingPackages,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Also, When I restore the package get error again "An error occurred while trying to restore the package. Unable to Find versio 1.7.1 of package jQuery.vsdoc"